# Get EF6 Proxy for POCO Entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

So I have code which has created a poco entity (from deserializing JSON).  I wish to enable lazy loading for the the entity, so I want Entity Framework to wrap my POCO object and give me an EF proxy that can lazy load navigation properties.

I've seen many answers for questions regarding getting the underlying poco entity from an EF proxy, but not the other way around given.  Given a poco entity how do you create an EF proxy wrapping it?

Both...

```
context.Set<TEntity>().Add(poco);
```

and...

```
context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(poco);
```

...return the poco entity is there a method somewhere that will give me a proxy for the poco?

I'm able to get proxied entities and lazy loading is working fine when I load an entity through...

```
context.Set<TEntity>().Where(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't lazy load navigation properties unless you are querying from the context. If you are loading the entity by the deserialization of JSON you need to use explicit loading.

```
//Example
context.Entry(poco).Reference(x => x.ReferenceProperty).Load();
context.Entry(poco).Collection(x => x.ReferenceCollection).Load();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: I was hoping after adding a poco entity to the context there was some way to enable lazy loading for it.  I suspected this might not be possible with the current framework.

Comment: Great idea for EF or even an explicit load of all reference properties in a single call.